# Angular JS $http config issue withCredentials & wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, webkit, http-get

I'm currently writing an ionic/angular mobile app. For the last hours I've been stuck with the following error in my code:

```js
function PromiseCtrl($scope, $http) {

    
    $http({
          method:'GET',
          url:"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + $scope.search + "&tomatoes=true&plot=full",
          withCredentials:false
      })
      .then(function(response){ $scope.data = response.data });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="PromiseCtrl">
     {{data}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this snippet doesn't need a lot of explanation, I'm simply requesting the data from the API and storing it into $scope.details.

**The fun thing is it does work in js fiddle or Microsoft Edge, but it gives me the following Error in WebKit which is a problem since it therefore doesn't work after I compile it with cordova and run the app on my android.**

Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Sherlock%20Holmes&tomatoes=true&plot=full.
>   Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials
>   flag is true. (14:35:05:491 | error, javascript)   at www/index.html

Comment: Can you post non working fiddle. This example works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/t3kcwc7y/265/

Comment: You're right, it works with some browsers in which I run the app. Unfortunately it doesn't do its magic when I'm running it in the WebKit browser. Which does mean that I cannot successfully use this application once its compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `withCredentials` to `false` in your `$httpProvider`.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
```

Comment: Hi Jaanus, thanks again for your fast reply. I still have the error:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Sherlock%20Holmes. Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true. (15:57:13:607 | error, javascript)
  at www/index.html

Comment: Sorry for the short comment, I'm still getting used to the comment function. It still gives me the same error. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3kcwc7y/269/ but the Error is still "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Sherlock%20Holmes. Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true. (15:57:13:607 | error, javascript)
  at www/index.html"

Comment: Which browser are you using exactly?

Comment: I'm testing on Netbeans Embedded Webkit browser since it uses the same engine as ios and android apps do when compiled by phonegap or cordova. Problem is there seems to be an issue with this particular setup which leaves me unable to successfully use the app on my phone.

Comment: I wonder if that browser even supports CORS. Can you try this code http://jsfiddle.net/t3kcwc7y/274/ on it.

Comment: Hi Jaanus, thanks for sticking with me. I tried your snippet in webkit and it supports: CORS supported (XHR). I hope this gives an indicator on what we are dealing with